# Model gets rendered multiple times when using useGLTP from react three drei

Tags: reactjs, three.js, gltf, react-three-fiber

I am using react three fiber and drei for getting and loading GLB file from server.

It's working with the below code but Model function get's called 4 times when it should be called only once.

Is there any way to call once and get Model component?

```
import React, { Suspense } from 'react';
import * as THREE from 'three';
import { Canvas } from '@react-three/fiber'
import { useGLTF,OrbitControls,Stage } from "@react-three/drei";

const Model = ({model_url})=>{
  console.log('Model created'); //<= this gets called 4 times
  let { scene } = useGLTF(model_url);
  return (
    <primitive scale={[1, 1, 1]} object={scene} /> 
  )
}


const ModelViewer = ()=>{

  return(
    <Suspense  fallback={<h1>Loading profile...</h1>}>
     <Canvas>
       <OrbitControls enablePan={true} enableZoom={true} enableRotate={true} />
       <Stage adjustCamera intensity={0.5} environment="city" preset="rembrandt">
         <group dispose={null}>
           <Model model_url={"https://******/model.glb"} /> 
         </group>
       </Stage>
     </Canvas> 
    </Suspense>
  );
}
```

Comment: ould your re-create this on a codesandbox ? Also try keeping the suspense around the model only, and use <Html> tag from drei to make HTML components render in 3D scope